# POI 3.9 How to fix xml parsing error in header with ooxml-schemas-1.1?

Tags: java, python, apache-poi, jython

I'm trying to create a docx Document in Jython using Apache POI 3.9 jars.
In this docx, I have to create a header and so add another jar to the collection: "ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar", the version which is compatible with POI 3.9.

Everythink works fine on the execution, but when I open the docx, it shows me an error :
"xml parsing error"

I've already tried to upgrade POI and he works.
Unfortunatly, I HAVE TO keep the 3.9 version.

So I need your help to make it work in this old version.

```
import sys

sys.path.append("true_poi\\ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar")
sys.path.append("true_poi\\poi-3.9.jar")
sys.path.append("true_poi\\poi-ooxml-3.9.jar")
sys.path.append("true_poi\\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar")
sys.path.append("true_poi\\xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar")
sys.path.append("true_poi\\dom4j-1.6.1.jar")

from org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel import XWPFDocument
from org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel import XWPFParagraph
from org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel import XWPFRun
from org.apache.poi.xwpf.model import XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy
from org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main import CTP
from java.io import File
from java.io import FileOutputStream

doc = XWPFDocument()
sectPr = doc.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr()
policy = XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(doc, sectPr)

ctpHeader = CTP.Factory.newInstance()
ctrHeader = ctpHeader.addNewR()
ctHeader = ctrHeader.addNewT()
ctHeader.setStringValue("HEADER")
headerPara = XWPFParagraph(ctpHeader, doc)
parsHeader = []
parsHeader.append(headerPara)
policy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, parsHeader)

para = doc.createParagraph()
run = para.createRun()
run.setText("BODY")

out = FileOutputStream(File("mypvc.docx"))
doc.write(out)
out.close()
```

Comment: What's the full exception and stack trace?

Comment: There is no stack trace in interpreter. Everything is OK like I said.
But when I open the docx he said "Sorry, we couldn't open mypvc.docx" xml parsing error line 2 column 144

Comment: https://imgur.com/OG5rgFo

Comment: [Take a look at all the fixes since 3.9, and especially all the security issued solved since then](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.9) (Apache POI 3.9 is almost 7 years old!), then get approval to upgrade to a supported, fixed version?

Comment: I can't upgrade, my hierarchy forbid me
But I think they lose their time, I've done so many test and you're as right as me, I can't do that without upgrading POI.

Comment: Just show them the list of known security issues

Comment: There is no solution except that ?

Comment: You're running 7 year old software with a load of known security issues, which is not supported by the open source project which you're not paying for, I'm not quite sure what sort of miracle you were expecting here.... There is a fix, upgrade to something secure and supported!